# How to display a Structures_Graph using php?

Tags: php, pear

I want to create a structured graph using pear module in php. So that i am using the Structures_Graph module from pear. I have mentioned the below sample code here. But i couldn't to display the graph image.

```
<?php
    require_once 'Structures/Graph.php';
    require_once 'Structures/Graph/Node.php';

    $nonDirectedGraph = new Structures_Graph(false);

    $nodeA = new Structures_Graph_Node();
    $nodeB = new Structures_Graph_Node();
    $nodeC = new Structures_Graph_Node();
    $nodeD = new Structures_Graph_Node();
    $nodeE = new Structures_Graph_Node();

    $nonDirectedGraph ->addNode($nodeA);
    $nonDirectedGraph ->addNode($nodeB);
    $nonDirectedGraph ->addNode($nodeC);
    $nonDirectedGraph ->addNode($nodeD);
    $nonDirectedGraph ->addNode($nodeE);

    $nodeA->connectTo($nodeB);
    $nodeB->connectTo($nodeC);
    $nodeB->connectTo($nodeD);
    $nodeD->connectTo($nodeC);
    $nodeC->connectTo($nodeE);
    $nodeE->connectTo($nodeD);
?>
```

My expected output like this. [image] But i couldn't do this.

Please guide to me..

Comment: the library doesn't contain any facility to display the graph as HTML, SVG or whatever. You have to write that yourself, or find a 3rd-party library that you can give some structured data to. On another SO answer someone suggested this: https://github.com/strathausen/dracula perhaps that or something similar will be of help to you. You can google for more alternatives. GraphViz is another one I have used in the past, which can take graph data and export it to SVG which you can then embed in a web page.

Comment: i also tried the GraphViz module. But the same problem image not displaying in browser.. so that i am trying the  Structures_Graph module..

Comment: well perhaps you did something wrong because Graphviz can be made to work, definitely. If you post your code for that perhaps somebody could help you. There are some easy-to-understand samples online of what to do, e.g. http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php Like I said, Structures_Graph only creates the data structure, it doesn't have any visualisation tools.

Comment: I don't know how to display the graph.. i have used the sample e.g. [link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php)  in my code. it doesn't display anything. i have one doubt if i display image, should i use the code "header("Content-type: image/png");" in my program..

Comment: do you get any errors? The sample doesn't suggest that you need to add the header, but perhaps you do. Why don't you try it and see? It would take you less time to test that yourself than type it here. Also, have you installed the Graphviz PHP libraries on your webserver?

Comment: Yes i am using xampp server, php 7.0 and pear Image Graphviz module also installed in windows 10. I didn't get any error message while run the sample graphviz code. any one pls guide me or share your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

[Structures_Graph](http://pear.php.net/package/Structures_Graph) is used by the PEAR installer to represent and resolve package dependencies. There is no in-built way to display those in a graphical manner, apart from `var_dump()` which is not what you want.

---

If you want a graph like the screenshot you gave, you need to use the [Image_GraphViz](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz/) package. Note that you need the graphviz `dot` binary for it. See the example and its notes: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php